# DalekJS Vs Selenium which tool is better to automate test workflows for an enterprise web solution?

Tags: selenium, ui-automation, dalekjs

I am working in a team responsible for development and maintenance of an enterprise web solution project where the **front end customer portal is developed with PHP** on **Yii framework and backend web application for back office operations is developed with Python on OpenERP**.

We are trying to automate the test workflows using only open source test automation tools are looking at options like **Selenium,DalekJS**.

My question is, keeping my project in mind which tool would be ideal to easily automate test workflows with a **great test coverage and easy maintainability**. We might have regular enhancements and fixes for both customer portal and back office web application. **Which tool would be better keeping my project in mind, is it Selenium or DalekJS?**

Any inputs/feedback or past experience would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Shashi Vardhan Andem,

unfortunatly it seems DalekJS is dead, unmaintained dependencies, last commit 2 years ago. We recently switched from dalekjs to http://webdriver.io/

So to answere your question. Definitly Selenium because it's gonna be still developed.

Cheers,

Dennis